# Marcar checkbox com Jquery

Tags: jquery

Estou montado uma tela, para escolher algumas opções.
Na verdade, são vários checkbox, com estilo.
Aqui eu até tirei a classe que faz o estilo do checkbox, para deixar visível.
Eu consigo dar o efeito, clicando na imagem, mas o script não marca o checkbox.
Seria possível marcar o checkbox quando eu clico na imagem?

Segue o que fiz até agora.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8"> 
<title>Check</title>

<style type="text/css">
.img-check{

 -webkit-transition: all 0.1s ease-out;
 -moz-transition: all 0.1s ease-out;
 -o-transition: all 0.1s ease-out;
 -ms-transition: all 0.1s ease-out;
 transition: all 0.1s ease-out; 
}

.img-check:hover{
 -webkit-transition-property: box-shadow;
    transition-property: box-shadow;
    -webkit-transition-duration: .1s;
    transition-duration: .1s;
    -webkit-transition-timing-function: ease-in;
    transition-timing-function: ease-in;
    box-shadow: 0 14px 42px 0 rgba(0,0,0,.2);
    text-decoration: none;
    cursor: pointer;
}

.check::before{
 content: '';
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    bottom: 0px;
    left: 0;
    right: 0;
 border: 5px solid #2f9780 !important;
 -webkit-transition: all 0.1s ease-out;
 -moz-transition: all 0.1s ease-out;
 -o-transition: all 0.1s ease-out;
 -ms-transition: all 0.1s ease-out;
 transition: all 0.1s ease-out; 
    z-index: 1;
}


.check:after{
 box-sizing: border-box;
    content: '';
    display: block;
    position: absolute;
    bottom: 5px;
    right: 10px;
    width: 52px;
    height: 53px;
    background-image: url(http://www.hostmove.com.br/images/check.png);
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-size: 100%;
}

.mediabox_media-frame {
    position: relative;
 margin-bottom: 30px;
}
</style>

<!-- Jquery -->
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://www.agenciamove.com.br/js/jquery-1.11.2.min.js"></script>

<!-- Boostrap -->
<link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.0/css/bootstrap.min.css"> 
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.0/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

<script type="text/javascript">
 $(document).ready(function(e){
  $(".img-check").click(function(){
   $(this).toggleClass("check");
  });
 });
</script>

</head>
<body>

<div class="container">
 <div class="row">
  <form method="get">
   <div class="form-group"> 
    <div class="col-xs-6 col-sm-4 col-md-4">
     <div class="mediabox_media-frame">
     <div class="img-check">
      <img src="http://www.hostmove.com.br/images/1.jpg" alt="..." class="img-responsive center-block">
      <input type="checkbox" name="chk1" id="item4" value="val1" class="" autocomplete="off">
     </div>
     </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-xs-6 col-sm-4 col-md-4">
     <div class="mediabox_media-frame">
     <div class="img-check">
      <img src="http://www.hostmove.com.br/images/2.jpg" alt="..." class="img-responsive center-block">
      <input type="checkbox" name="chk1" id="item4" value="val2" class="" autocomplete="off">
     </div>
     </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-xs-6 col-sm-4 col-md-4">
     <div class="mediabox_media-frame">
     <div class="img-check">
      <img src="http://www.hostmove.com.br/images/3.jpg" alt="..." class="img-responsive center-block">
      <input type="checkbox" name="chk1" id="item4" value="val3" class="" autocomplete="off">
     </div>
     </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-xs-6 col-sm-4 col-md-4">
     <div class="mediabox_media-frame">
     <div class="img-check">
      <img src="http://www.hostmove.com.br/images/4.jpg" alt="..." class="img-responsive center-block">
      <input type="checkbox" name="chk1" id="item4" value="val4" class="" autocomplete="off">
     </div>
     </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-xs-6 col-sm-4 col-md-4">
     <div class="mediabox_media-frame">
     <div class="img-check">
      <img src="http://www.hostmove.com.br/images/5.jpg" alt="..." class="img-responsive center-block">
      <input type="checkbox" name="chk1" id="item4" value="val5" class="" autocomplete="off">
     </div>
     </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-xs-6 col-sm-4 col-md-4">
     <div class="mediabox_media-frame">
     <div class="img-check">
      <img src="http://www.hostmove.com.br/images/6.jpg" alt="..." class="img-responsive center-block">
      <input type="checkbox" name="chk1" id="item4" value="val6" class="" autocomplete="off">
     </div>
     </div>
    </div>    
   </div>

   <!-- <input type="submit" value="Check Item" class="btn btn-success"> -->
  
  </form>
 </div> 
</div>

</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sim, é possível. :)

Segue o exemplo abaixo:

```js
$(document).ready(function(e){
  $(".img-check").click(function(){
    $(this).toggleClass("check");
    
    let checkbox = $(this).find('input[type="checkbox"]');
    
    if (! checkbox.is(':checked')) {
      checkbox.prop('checked', true);
    } else {
      checkbox.prop('checked', false);
    }
  });
});
```

```css
.img-check
{
  -webkit-transition: all 0.1s ease-out;
  -moz-transition: all 0.1s ease-out;
  -o-transition: all 0.1s ease-out;
  -ms-transition: all 0.1s ease-out;
  transition: all 0.1s ease-out; 
}

.img-check:hover
{
  -webkit-transition-property: box-shadow;
  transition-property: box-shadow;
  -webkit-transition-duration: .1s;
  transition-duration: .1s;
  -webkit-transition-timing-function: ease-in;
  transition-timing-function: ease-in;
  box-shadow: 0 14px 42px 0 rgba(0,0,0,.2);
  text-decoration: none;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.check::before
{
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  bottom: 0px;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  border: 5px solid #2f9780 !important;
  -webkit-transition: all 0.1s ease-out;
  -moz-transition: all 0.1s ease-out;
  -o-transition: all 0.1s ease-out;
  -ms-transition: all 0.1s ease-out;
  transition: all 0.1s ease-out; 
  z-index: 1;
}

.check:after
{
  box-sizing: border-box;
  content: '';
  display: block;
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 5px;
  right: 10px;
  width: 52px;
  height: 53px;
  background-image: url('http://www.hostmove.com.br/images/check.png');
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-size: 100%;
}

.mediabox_media-frame
{
  position: relative;
  margin-bottom: 30px;
}
```

```html
<link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.0/css/bootstrap.min.css"> 

<script type="text/javascript" src="https://www.agenciamove.com.br/js/jquery-1.11.2.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.0/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

<div class="container">
  <div class="row">
    <form method="get">
      <div class="form-group"> 
        <div class="col-xs-6 col-sm-4 col-md-4">
          <div class="mediabox_media-frame">
            <div class="img-check">
              <img src="http://www.hostmove.com.br/images/1.jpg" alt="..." class="img-responsive center-block">
              <input type="checkbox" name="chk1" id="item4" value="val1" class="" autocomplete="off">
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-xs-6 col-sm-4 col-md-4">
          <div class="mediabox_media-frame">
            <div class="img-check">
              <img src="http://www.hostmove.com.br/images/2.jpg" alt="..." class="img-responsive center-block">
              <input type="checkbox" name="chk1" id="item4" value="val2" class="" autocomplete="off">
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-xs-6 col-sm-4 col-md-4">
          <div class="mediabox_media-frame">
            <div class="img-check">
              <img src="http://www.hostmove.com.br/images/3.jpg" alt="..." class="img-responsive center-block">
              <input type="checkbox" name="chk1" id="item4" value="val3" class="" autocomplete="off">
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-xs-6 col-sm-4 col-md-4">
          <div class="mediabox_media-frame">
            <div class="img-check">
              <img src="http://www.hostmove.com.br/images/4.jpg" alt="..." class="img-responsive center-block">
              <input type="checkbox" name="chk1" id="item4" value="val4" class="" autocomplete="off">
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-xs-6 col-sm-4 col-md-4">
          <div class="mediabox_media-frame">
            <div class="img-check">
              <img src="http://www.hostmove.com.br/images/5.jpg" alt="..." class="img-responsive center-block">
              <input type="checkbox" name="chk1" id="item4" value="val5" class="" autocomplete="off">
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-xs-6 col-sm-4 col-md-4">
          <div class="mediabox_media-frame">
            <div class="img-check">
              <img src="http://www.hostmove.com.br/images/6.jpg" alt="..." class="img-responsive center-block">
              <input type="checkbox" name="chk1" id="item4" value="val6" class="" autocomplete="off">
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>    
      </div>
      <!-- <input type="submit" value="Check Item" class="btn btn-success"> -->
    </form>
  </div>
</div>
```